# Mobile connectivity in Israel, in and outside small and large cities?

Tags: cellphones, israel

What is mobile connectivity like in Israel, especially outside the cities but also in the smaller cities?  For example, will I be able to use GetTaxi, the Israeli equivalent of Uber, at the Beit She’an / Sheik Hussein – Northern border crossing (between Tiberias and Jerash)?  More generally, will there be connectivity in smaller cities, along the major roads between cities, and at tourist attractions?

Answer (score 7):

Israel is a small country that *looooves* its mobiles.  Excluding some bits of the Negev desert, the entire country is blanketed with mobile phone networks, and you're not going to have any trouble anywhere populated.

Here's an [unofficial coverage](http://opensignal.com/networks/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C/pelephone-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8) map for Pelephone, one of the big local operators.  Note that this is crowdsourced from users, and the actual coverage is considerably better.  Also, the Palestinian bits have their own operators, which is why the West Bank and Gaza show up as blank.

Comment: The coverage looks great until you zoom in. Then it looks spotty in some areas.

Comment: "Note that this is crowdsourced from users, and the actual coverage is considerably better."  Also, I've visited Israel ~6 times, and can't ever recall needing coverage and not having it.

Answer (score 2):

The [first answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44152/1972) is correct, there are cellular antennas spread everywhere in Israel, official map is available in [this link](http://govmap.gov.il/sviva?c=FTCrdFtsdcTnQSRhxxU4Hg%3d%3d%7CEdObpb4H3w%2bIx9d5KNUd%2fQ%3d%3d&z=6&b=0&lay=Antena_Hakama%7Ccell_active).

The map is in Hebrew, but you can just zoom in on any part to see the cellular coverage.

Sample screenshot from Tel Aviv area:

> [image]

[image] - [Partner Communications Company Orange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partner_Communications_Company)

[image] - [Cellcom (Israel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellcom_(Israel))

[image] - [Pelephone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelephone)

Comment: `We have cellular antennas everywhere` - who is `we`? :)

Comment: @JoErNanO 1:0, fixed. :)

Comment: The coverage seems to be very dense in populated areas but much less so elsewhere.  Will I be able to use GetTaxi, the Israeli equivalent of Uber, at the Beit She’an / Sheik Hussein – Northern border crossing (between Tiberias and Jerash)?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC yes, you should be able to use it in all populated areas of both Israel and Palestine. As the other answer mentions, there is [Paltel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paltel) cellular provider, which covers most of the areas under Palestinian control.